# Hide element until one minute before the top of every 4th hour

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a div that warns the user of my app demo that its database is about to be reset.

I used to reset the database every hour, and used a warning that was contained in a `div` that was hidden until one minute before the top of each hour.

`<div id="database-reset-warning" style="display:<?php if (date('i') >=55){echo 'inline';}else{echo 'none';} ?>;">`

But now the database is being reset once every four hours. Therefore, I would like the `div` to be hidden until **one minute before the top of every 4th hour** *based on the server's time*.

In other words:

- 23:59:00 PST
- 03:59:00 PST
- 07:59:00 PST
- 11:59:00 PST
- 15:59:00 PST
- 19:59:00 PST

I would prefer a solution in either PHP or jQuery if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in PHP assuming the server is in PST timezone. Check every minute.

```html
$clock = ["23:59", "03:59", "07:59", "11:59", "15:59", "19:59"];

$actualTime = new Date("HH:mm");
if ( in_array( $actualTime, $clock)) {
// RESET
}
```